# good accuracy, less loss, wrong classe predict Tf/keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i made a program that predict characters in keras using EMNIST by class as a dataset and the training took me 10 hours in gpu i made an CNN architecture that gives me good accuracy and less loss
as shown in both images and also the predict picture i got .. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnSEm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q11Yn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxVsH.png)

so i use in my program 1 python file for training and other for predicting word by taking each character seperated.
training file contain this architecture :

`````
K.set_learning_phase(1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Reshape((28,28,1), input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=(28,28,1),
                         activation='relu',padding='same',
                        kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (5,5),activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64,(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same', 
``kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))``

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(62, activation='softmax'))

#opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
#opt = optimizers.Adadelta()
opt = optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.002, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, 
`decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, 
metrics=`['accuracy'])


print(model.summary())
history = model.fit(train_images,train_labels,validation_data=(test_images, 
``test_labels), 

batch_size=128, epochs=200)

    #evaluating model on test data. will take time
    scores = model.evaluate(test_images,test_labels, verbose = 0)
    print("Accuracy: %.2f%%"%(scores[1]*100))````
`````

and the code for loading the model and predicting the characters

```
`json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)


loaded_model.load_weights('model.h5')

model = loaded_model


print('Model successfully loaded')

characters = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 
'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
          'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 
'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
          'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 
't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# enter input image here
image = cv2.imread('example.png')

height, width, depth = image.shape

# resizing the image to find spaces better
image = cv2.resize(image, dsize=(width * 5, height * 4), 
interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
# grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# binary
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# dilation
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

# adding GaussianBlur
gsblur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_dilation, (5, 5), 0)

# find contours
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(gsblur.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

m = list()
# sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
pchl = list()
dp = image.copy()
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
# Get bounding box
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
cv2.rectangle(dp, (x - 10, y - 10), (x + w + 10, y + h + 10), (90, 0, 255), 
9)

plt.imshow(dp)
plt.show()
plt.close()

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
# Get bounding box
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
# Getting ROI
roi = image[y - 10:y + h + 10, x - 10:x + w + 10]
roi = cv2.resize(roi, dsize=(28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

roi = np.array(roi)
t = np.copy(roi)
t = t / 255.0
t = 1 - t
t = t.reshape(1, 784)
m.append(roi)
pred = model.predict_classes(t)
pchl.append(pred)

pcw = list()
interp = 'bilinear'
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(sorted_ctrs), sharex=True, figsize=(1, 
len(sorted_ctrs)))
for i in range(len(pchl)):
# print (pchl[i][0])
pcw.append(characters[pchl[i][0]])
axs[i].set_title('-------> predicted letter: ' + characters[pchl[i][0]], 
x=2.5, y=0.24)
axs[i].imshow(m[i], interpolation=interp)

plt.show()

predstring = ''.join(pcw)
print('Predicted String: ' + predstring)
```

`
the code for creating the plots

```
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('Accuracy')
#plt.show()
#plt.close()

# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('Loss')
```

the output i get is in image i've put above thanks for giving advices and help.

Comment: What are the red and green lines in your second picture? Also, based on the first picture, it looks like you have a case of model overfit.

Comment: thanks for responding, i modify the post  could you please recheck the the main post i did how i made them.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr what do you suggest for the overfit ?

Comment: I would simplify the structure of the neural network, either by shaving off a couple of the layers and/or reducing the number of nodes per layer. There is no correct answer here. You would have to experiment with different architectures but considering the scope of your problem, you don't need a deep NN to solve this problem. Also, since this is an iterative approach, just test with 20 epochs and tweak the params with each experiment.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr okay thanks, would you estimate what would be the loss value so i can stop changing the architecture, and also do you thinks that i can get good accuracy and loss in 20 epochs ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say what the loss value. There's no right or wrong answer. It's all about achieving a better score than your previous iteration. And I was only suggesting 20 epochs because in your picture, the test accuracy got worse before even hitting 25 epochs. You may have to adjust the epoch later when you have a more mature model, but the general intuition is that you stop when your accuracy starts to flatline.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is clearly overfitting, which you can see as your test accuracy clearly diverges from your training accuracy.

You might want to look into regularization techniques to avoid this.

Comment: thanks for responding, could you tell me sir whether its  a good architecture i made there or not.